# continues sound frequency using Matlab

Tags: matlab, frequency

I am working on a project to analyze the frequency of a continues sound ( guitar ). I know how to use FFT on a sound file and find the frequency then plot it. The question is how if I want a real time continues sound? I don't need to plot the frequency I just need to find the value of that frequency.

Comment: Assuming only one note is played, its frequency would simply be the frequency for which the value of the spectrogram you get from FFT is maximal. Be sure to get the frequency in Hz and not in rad/sec.

Comment: While this other question is closed, you might want to read through it anyway, re: finding "frequency" of musical notes: stackoverflow.com/questions/4227420/